# Perfect minimal hash for mathematical combinations

Tags: algorithm, hash, combinations, perfect-hash

First, define two integers `N` and `K`, where `N >= K`, both known at compile time. For example: `N = 8` and `K = 3`.

Next, define a set of integers `[0, N)` (or `[1, N]` if that makes the answer simpler) and call it `S`. For example: `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`

The number of subsets of `S` with `K` elements is given by the formula `C(N, K)`. Example

My problem is this: Create a perfect minimal hash for those subsets. The size of the example hash table will be `C(8, 3)` or `56`.

I don't care about ordering, only that there be 56 entries in the hash table, and that I can determine the hash quickly from a set of `K` integers. I also don't care about reversibility.

Example hash: `hash({5, 2, 3}) = 42`. (The number 42 isn't important, at least not here)

Is there a generic algorithm for this that will work with any values of `N` and `K`? I wasn't able to find one by searching Google, or my own naive efforts.

Comment: Just to be clear; what are the input and output of your hash function?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Edited. Input is one of the possible combinations, output is an integer in [0, C(N, K)).

Answer (score 3):

There is an algorithm to code and decode a combination into its number in the lexicographical order of all combinations with a given fixed `K`. The algorithm is linear to `N` for both code and decode of the combination. What language are you interested in?

EDIT: here is example code in c++(it founds the lexicographical number of a combination in the sequence of **all** combinations of n elements as opposed to the ones with `k` elements but is really good starting point):

```
typedef long long ll;

// Returns the number in the lexicographical order of all combinations of n numbers
// of the provided combination. 
ll code(vector<int> a,int n)
{
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    int cur = 0;
    int m = a.size();

    ll res =0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == cur+1)
        {
            res++;
            cur = a[i];
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            res++;
            int number_of_greater_nums = n - a[i];
            for(int j = a[i]-1,increment=1;j>cur;j--,increment++)
                res += 1LL << (number_of_greater_nums+increment);
            cur = a[i];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
// Takes the lexicographical code of a combination of n numbers and returns the 
// combination
vector<int> decode(ll kod, int n)
{
    vector<int> res;
    int cur = 0;

    int left = n; // Out of how many numbers are we left to choose.
    while(kod)
    {
        ll all = 1LL << left;// how many are the total combinations
        for(int i=n;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(all - (1LL << (n-i+1)) +1 <= kod)
            {
                res.push_back(i);
                left = n-i;
                kod -= all - (1LL << (n-i+1)) +1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

I am sorry I have an algorithm for the problem you are asking for right now, but I believe it will be a good exercise to try to **understand** what I do above. Truth is this is one of the algorithms I teach in the course "Design and analysis of algorithms" and that is why I had it pre-written.

Comment: Is there no constant time algorithm? I'd really prefer that.

Comment: @KendallFrey You can not have a constant time algorithm - your input is of size `N` (for the problem I solve above)!  You can not perform better than the algorithm above. I guess you can write a O(K) solution for your problem by slightly modifying the solution above and again you **can't perform better** as this is the input size.

Comment: Sorry, by constant time I meant O(K). K will be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @KendallFrey I believe you can get as low as `O(K)` assuming you have already calculated the powers of two up to `N`. Still I think that as K will probably be in the order of N there will not be a huge difference(Number of combinations grows really fast so both N and K will be quite small).

Comment: @KendallFrey is it possible that you got the complexity for my solution wrong? My solution is linear to the number of numbers in S namely `N`, not to the number of possible combinations.

Comment: I understand the `O(N)` complexity, but it seems excessive to me because my specific implementation will have `N` quite large (< 100 though).

Comment: Why would you cache powers of two though? A bitshift is one of the fastest things you can do

Comment: @harold true. I can't seem to remember why I did it and it makes no sense to me now :). I will fix that

Comment: @izomorphius sort(a.begin(),a.end()) is not linear

Comment: it is if your values are in small range. Seems there is optimization to use count sort in such cases. Verified on gcc 4.3 looong ago

Answer (score 1):

This is what you (and I) need:

`hash()` maps `k-tuples` from `[1..n]` onto the set `1..C(n,k)\subset N`.
The effort is `k` subtractions (and `O(k)` is a lower bound anyway, see Strandjev's remark above):

```
// bino[n][k] is (n "over" k) = C(n,k) = {n \choose k}
// these are assumed to be precomputed globals

int hash(V a,int n, int k) {// V is assumed to be ordered, a_k<...<a_1
  // hash(a_k,..,a_2,a_1) = (n k) - sum_(i=1)^k (n-a_i   i) 
  // ii is "inverse i", runs from left to right

  int res = bino[n][k];
  int i;

  for(unsigned int ii = 0; ii < a.size(); ++ii) {
    i = a.size() - ii;   
    res = res - bino[n-a[ii]][i];
  }
  return res;
}
```